# How do I access a file share on a non-domain Windows 10 PC using my domain user account?

Tags: windows, file-sharing

I'm a remote worker and I have two Windows 10 laptops. Both laptops are connected wirelessly to the same router at home. I log into my personal laptop with a Microsoft account. I log into my work laptop with my company email address. I can also log in to the same account using `DOMAIN\USERNAME`. Windows Settings shows my work laptop is connected to my company's Azure AD, but it is not joined to the domain. (It is a member of WORKGROUP.) Local Users and Groups does not show my user account, but it is listed as a member of the local Administrators group as `DOMAIN\USERNAME`. I am able to VPN to my company network as needed, but most of the time I do not use the VPN.

How do I access network shares on my work laptop from my personal laptop? When I try to connect using `\\COMPUTERNAME` I am prompted for credentials. No matter what I use, I get the error "The user name or password is incorrect." I've tried all of the following:

```
username@domain.com
DOMAIN\USERNAME
domain.com\username
MicrosoftAccount\username@domain.com
PCNAME\USERNAME
```

I've verified that I can log on locally to my work laptop with `username@domain.com` or `DOMAIN\USERNAME`, so I know I have the correct credentials and password.

Comment: Maybe try `\\COMPUTERNAME.DOMAIN`

Comment: @dan1st That does not work. It can't even find the computer when I try that. Since neither laptop is on the domain, I wouldn't expect it to work. I am able to connect just fine using `\\COMPUTERNAME\SHARE`; the issue is with the authentication. I don't know what username\password combination to use.

Comment: What about `.\USERNAME` as user?

Comment: @dan1st Nope, that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting variations of this question on two different sites, no one has provided any solution to the question as stated. Based on feedback I received elsewhere, it appears that it is not possible to connect to a target computer with credentials for a domain account (even if it is not joined to the domain) unless the source computer is also connected to Azure AD. So the first workaround is to join the source computer to Azure AD (Settings -> Accounts -> Access work or school -> Connect).

Since this is a personal laptop, I don't wish to connect it to my work Azure AD. So the other workaround would be to create a local (non-domain) account on the target (work) computer, grant access to the file share, and connect using this account. I don't like that it requires creating an additional account that I will never use to log in locally, but it seems to be the better of the two undesirable choices.

Answer (score -2):

Some explanations and steps are outlined here: https://techdirectarchive.com/2023/11/08/how-to-access-shared-resources-from-two-different-domains/

> ##### Possible Approaches
>
> Most times, you are required to set up a Domain trust to achieve this. **Domain Trusts** enable one domain to recognize the users and groups in another domain. There are different types of trusts, including one-way and two-way trusts, depending on the level of access and authentication required. But, when the two domains are in separate Active Directory forests. You will have to set up Forest Trusts to enable access.
>
> Other options are **VPN or Direct Network Connection**, and ensuring all the required network configurations are in place. But, I will not be using any of these approaches.
>
> Users from one domain can access shared resources in another domain by providing credentials during authentication. This can be achieved by using the “username” prefix with the domain name. For example (“TechDirect\Christian”). This method works great due to the proprietary local area network (LAN) protocols like NetBIOS and NetBEUI. This method supports domain trust where each domain is an island of its own.